# Discount codes for recurring profiles

Tags: discount, recurring

I am looking at the possibilities of having a discount code applied to a recurring profile.
For instance, a customers subscribes our subscription (basis = 12 months) at 34.99 but with the special promotion he will get 10 % off for the 12 months. Is this possible ? If yes, how ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not with stock Magento, here's [one implementation](http://store.cryozonic.com/documentation/magento-1-stripe-subscriptions#stripe-subscriptions-coupons) that does it.